# Replacing Abbreviation strings (U.S.A.) to USA using sed command

Tags: awk, sed

How to use the sed command to replace a string like "U.S.A." to "USA" or "D.A.R.P.A." to DARPA. The " is not part of the string.

So my goal is to replace only the abbreviations from a huge text.

I tried  `sed "s/.//g" file.txt >file2.txt` but this replaces all the occurences of dots.

Then i tried a bunch of different combinations like:

`sed "s/([A-Z]\.)+/[A-Z]/g" file.txt >file2.txt`
which clearly doesn't work.

apparently the terminal does not accept () brackets or nested brackets

if I want to replace a letter followed by a dot with something very specific i can do that using `sed "s/[A-Z]/a/g" file.txt >file2.txt`

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the dots? (example, sed 's/\.//g'  )

Comment: Hi I tried a bunch of different combinations I'll edit thr original question. Apologize for the vague description

Comment: I want to make clear that I could match an abbreviation string using (([A-Z])\.)+  pattern and many other combinations. I need help with the sed command. I also tried finding my specific case in this online tutorial http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-30 too and could not find anything relevant hence I as a last resort I've posted a question here. Last I checked this was a space where you could ask questions whose answer you didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that OP wants to just delete the dots that occur after uppercase alphabets

```
$ s='U.S.A. foo.bar D.A.R.P.A. a.b.'
$ echo "$s" | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)\./\1/g'
USA foo.bar DARPA a.b.

$ # if ERE is available as -E or -r option
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/([A-Z])\./\1/g'
USA foo.bar DARPA a.b.
```

- `\([A-Z]\)` is [capture group](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions) and `\1` is back-reference to that matched string
- `\.` as `.` is a meta-character, it needs to be escaped to match it
- See also [wooledge quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) to know when to use single/double quotes

Answer (score 1):

Following `sed` may help you on same, it is simple `sed` based on its logic `sed s/old_value/new_value/g`.

```
echo "U.S.A." | sed 's/\.//g'
```

**Solution 2nd:** As OP has changed his question so adding this answer too now.
Let's say we have following Input_file.

```
cat Input_file
U.S.A. D.A.R.P.A.
fewqfewfew fwefjwefu1e13rvnoi.wbvwvnwv
D.A.R.P.A. wnvwnvnewv nwvnrwnvrwnvrw


awk --re-interval '
{
  val=$0;
  while(match(val,/([a-zA-Z]{1,}\.{1,}){1,}/)){
    value=value1=substr(val,RSTART,RLENGTH);
    gsub(/\./,"",value1);
    sub(value,value1,$0);
    val=substr(val,RSTART+RLENGTH)}
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
USA DARPA
fewqfewfew fwefjwefu1e13rvnoiwbvwvnwv
DARPA wnvwnvnewv nwvnrwnvrwnvrw
```

***NOTE:*** My `awk` is of old version in case you have latest version of `awk` then you need not to use `--re-interval` in above code then.

Comment: Hi I edited my question. I want to replace . characters of specific words only

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 thanks. Can you tell what the last '1' in the pattern does?

Comment: @ketanShah, `awk` works on method of condition and action. So I am making condition TRUE here by mentioning `1` and not mentioning any action so default print of current line will happen.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the awk solution seems to be just a long way of doing `sed 's/\.//g'`.. am I missing something?

Comment: @Sundeep, my 1st solution is that only :) Later OP told that it should be only happening(substitution) for Abbreviations so I added 2nd solution then too.

Comment: in that case just use sed, or gensub with gawk... imo match/substr is a convoluted solution..

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sed

```
sed -E ':A;s/([A-Z]\.)([A-Z]\.{1,})/.\1.\2/;tA;s/(\.{1,})([A-Z])(\.)/\2/g' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\b\([[:upper:]]\)\b\./\1/g' file
```

This removes `.`'s preceded by single character upper-case words.